# Stanford CoreNLP Conll output

Tags: output, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP version 3.4. I want output in Conll format for annotators `tokenize`, `ssplit`,`pos`, `lemma`, and `ner`. However on executing the command `java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.4.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.4-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-3.4.jar -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file input.txt -outputFormat conll` it shows following error.

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.OutputFormat.CONLL
> >         at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
> >         at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$OutputFormat.valueOf(StanfordCoreNLP.java:86)
> >         at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1167)
> >         at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1448)

P.S: I don't want to annotate for dependencies.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CoNLL output formatter was added in version 3.5.0. Upgrade your version and this error should go away.